# Erratic MySQL results using php

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP and MySQL query returns wrong information.

for the purpose of this Query - $PortalAdvertiserOne and $PortalAdvertiserTwo is INT

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM 100_advertisers_campaigns 
        WHERE vendor_owner IN($PortalAdvertiserOne,$PortalAdvertiserTwo)
          AND ad_section_news = 'Y' 
          AND ad_position = 2 
        ORDER 
           BY RAND() 
        LIMIT 1
     ) x 
 ORDER 
    BY ad_id";
```

The Query returns everything perfect except where "ad_position" is supposed to return only records with 2, this query returns records from my table with 1, 2, 3 and 4. It does not seem to filter that part of the query.

What am i missing ?

Comment: What is the field type of ad_position?

Comment: The Field is INT (11 in lenght)

Comment: Then why having the single quotes? It could matter

Answer (score 2):

Try with the () rounding the **or**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM 100_advertisers_campaigns WHERE (vendor_owner = $PortalAdvertiserOne or vendor_owner = $PortalAdvertiserTwo and ad_section_news = 'Y') and ad_position = '2' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) x ORDER BY ad_id";
```

Comment: To simplify this solution you could change braced _or_ part to `WHERE vendor_owner IN ($PortalAdvertiserOne, $PortalAdvertiserTwo) AND ...`